# unit test for changing query data

Tags: python, unit-testing

usually I find on Stackoverflow what I'm searching but in this particular case not (at least I didn't noticed that it answers my question...).

Let's say I have some data I receive from a database via a query, which is changing (every second/minute or so). As an example, let's take the last traded price for a share of google on yahoo finance. 
I wrote a method in Python which grabs that price for me. Now I try to test this method, but I don't know how.

I thought about different approaches:
I thought I could grab the query via a request and compare the price grabbed by the method. But then I would probably compare my method with itself and the price could have changed in the time frame between the calls and i would get an exception. So I would assume this is not the best way to go.

I read something about syntactic tests of data bases but still I need to know if I get the right call because, because I will process this number later on again with data which is under constant change.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `mock` library

Comment: I know mock (a little bit), but I don't have an idea how to use that in that case. Could you explain that in more detail for me?

Thanks!

Comment: i'm no expert, but it'd probably look like: mock the db call, and return a dummy value and test your code. How you'd mock the db call is the harder part. if this "db" call is a `requests` call, you can look up `httmock` library

Comment: Thanks! Yes it's a requests call. I will check that out!